# Any resources/bibliography for periodic solutions and periodic boundary conditions of a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, periodic-functions

can anyone recommend good books and/or articles for the mathematical analysis of periodic solutions of a PDE, for example something like

$$u(t)-u''(t)=f(t) $$ with $u(0)=u(1)$ and $u'(0)=u'(1)$ ?

Something that treats the weak formulations, regularity... etc.

I'm good with googling things but so far nothing of note has popped up, and the wikipedia article doesn't really give me what I'm looking for. Thanks !

Comment: This question is extremely broad. And besides, that's an ODE, not PDE...

Comment: @HansLundmark yeah realized i posted the ode instead of the pde right after submitting, but it's the same spirit really... do you have any books that you think can relate to this question ?

Comment: In my opinion, "Fourier Analysis and Partial Differential Equations" by Rafael Iorio and Valeria de Magalhães offers a fairly wide (and introductory) treatment of periodic problems in PDEs. Chapter 2 and 3 deal with the basic theory of Fourier Series and Periodic Distributions / Sobolev spaces.  Part II of the book explores applications to Linear and Non-linear evolution problems with periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: @J.DavidBeltran thank you so much !